# Calling main method with null in Java

Tags: java

Can i know why below code would print "Hello World!" three times. ?

```
class Main {
static int count = 0;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if(count<3) {
        count++;
        main(null);
    } else {
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
  }
}
```

I know the main method is being called three times, but can the main method accept null as argument ? Why would this not come out of the main method during the first return statement execution, seems that else block is getting executed thrice.

Comment: Yes, main method have a signature as any other method. And array in java are nullable.

Comment: Why would the `else` block be executed thrice? It gets executed once, when `count` reaches a value of 3, then the calls to `main` begins ending, and the `main(null)` calls return, leading to the code printing the text.

Comment: Check what recursive functions are.

Comment: My suggestion is to run this program in a debugger. That way you can see the details of the program as it runs. Most IDEs have debugged and they are easy to use.

Comment: Are  you expecting that executing one 'return' exits all 3 concurrent activations of main?  That's not how it works, though it seems to be a popular misconception amongst Java beginners.  Perhaps it is wrongly explained as "returns from the method" rather than "returns from the current activation of the method".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'can you call main with null arguments' part was addressed by the other answer.  This answer is about why there are 3 lines printed, as you ask us in the body of the question.

It's easier to see the logic if you rearrange the code a little.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (count<3) {
        count++;
        main(null);
        System.out.println("Hello World!");    
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

That is functionally the same as what you wrote: in your original code, there are only two paths through the code, one where count is less than 3, and one where it isn't.

When count is not less than 3, we immediately execute a 'return', which means the 'print' doesn't happen on this particular call to 'main'.  So the print only happens when count is less than 3, which means it might as well be in the 'if count < 3' part.

The rearrangement should (I hope) make it easier to see that we execute the 'print' exactly as many times as we execute 'main' with count less than 3, which is to say, 3 times.

The 'else return' clause adds nothing, so the code can further be reduced:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (count<3) {
        count++;
        main(null);
        System.out.println("Hello World!");    
    }
}
```

which for my taste makes it even clearer.

The lesson here: straightforward layout makes code flow easier to understand.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it can, because args[] is not actually being used.

If your code was trying to actually call args.something(), then the JVM would notice that you were trying to invoke a method on a null object, and it would throw a NullPointerException.